# Error en PHP Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\nxammp\htdocs\Proyecto_Animales en peligro de exincion\pro.php on line 14
```

```
Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\nxammp\htdocs\Proyecto_Animales en peligro de exincion\pro.php on line 27
```

El codigo:

```php
<?php
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

session_start();

$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

include('conexion.php');

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registros");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM  datos where usuario='$usuario' and contraseña='$contraseña'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas) {
    header("location:PaginaPrincipal.php");
} else { ?>
    <?php
    include("sesion.html");
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR EN LA AUTENTIFICACION</h1>
    <?php
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Debes dar mas información sobre que quieres conseguir, además te recomiendo usar un titulo mas descriptivo ya que los usuarios suelen huir de las preguntas "no se que hacer" y similares.

Comment: Está fallando la consulta, por lo que `mysqli_query` te está devolviendo un null que es lo que le estás pasando a `mysqli_num_rows`. Es posible que el problema sea por utilizar la ñ en la variable o columna, pero puede ser también debido a otras cosas como inyección o algún error en los nombres de tablas y columnas.

Comment: Como te indicaron más arriba, haz que el título de tu pregunta sea más descriptivo. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [error al ejecutar mysqli\_num\_rows() y mysqli\_free\_result()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305646/error-al-ejecutar-mysqli-num-rows-y-mysqli-free-result)

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$consulta` y pruébalo directamente en MySQL.

Comment: La variable `$resultado` es un booleao, lo que quiere decir que la consulta esta fallando. Te recomiendo revisar [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597). Por otro lado, tu código es [sensible a Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está diciendo es que ambas funciones, necesitan que el parametro que les pasas sea un parametro del tipo mysqli_result y le estas pasando uno del tipo bool.

Entonces, como el parametro que le estás pasando es `$resultado`, podrías deducir que por algún motivo, cuando usas `$resultado`, dicha variable es del tipo bool.

El valor a `$resultado` se lo das en `$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);`, con lo cual, algo está fallando en el query.

Lo más normal suele ser que has puesto el nombre de alguna tabla o de alguna columna mal. En este caso, como no conocemos la estructura de tu base de datos ni los nombres de las columnas, y a simple vista parecería que está bien la consulta, lo que se me ocurre es ( pese a que algunas veces mysql acepta carecteres "especiales" para nombrar las tablas / columnas ), el poner una eñe en `contraseña` sea el causante del error.

Prueba a cambiar el nombre de la columna a `contrasena` por ejemplo ( y en el código también ), a ver si eso soluciona el problema.